# problems with xlsxwriter "workbook.close()" python library

Tags: python

I am having problems the following problem with the generation of an excel file: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Reportes/ Reportes_enviados_20180806.xls" where the "Reports" folder exists, and has all the permissions. When I get to the `woorbook.close()` is where this problem occurs, any idea where the error might be?

```
def generarReporte(regsCurRegx):
    escribirLog("***Se Inicia la Generación del Excel***")

    #Crea a sobreescribe el excel en la ruta especificada
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/sysx/proyectos/afore/felicitacioncumpleafoauto/Reportes/Reportes_enviados_'+time.strftime("%Y")+time.strftime("%m")+time.strftime("%d")+'.xls')
    worksheetReg = workbook.add_worksheet(u'Reportes_enviados')

    #Crea la cabecera del excel
    cabReg = ('Fecha', 'Nombre', 'Apellido paterno', 'Apellido materno', 'CURP', 'NSS',
            'Correo', u'Contactación', 'Forma de envio', u'Motivo no contactación')

    cont_reg = 0

    #Da estilo a la cabecera
    formatTitle = workbook.add_format()
    formatTitle.set_font_size(10)
    formatTitle.set_font_name('Arial')
    formatTitle.set_bold()
    formatTitle.set_align('center')
    formatTitle.set_align('vcenter')
    formatTitle.set_bg_color('green')
    formatTitle.set_font_color('white')

    #Da estilos a las celdas
    format = workbook.add_format()
    format.set_font_size(10)
    format.set_font_name('Arial')
    format.set_align('center')

    worksheetReg.set_column(0, 0, 17)
    worksheetReg.set_column(1, 10, 30)
    worksheetReg.set_row(0, 20)
    # Se inicia desde la primera celda. Las filas y columnas son inicializadas en cero
    row = 0
    col = 0

    # for para escribir el encabezado
    for nomCol in (cabReg):
        worksheetReg.write(row, col, nomCol, formatTitle)
        col += 1

    escribirLog("Se escribe el encabezado en el excel")

    row+=1
    col=0


    for fecha,nombre,paterno,materno,curp,nss,correo,enviocorreo,formaenvio,causa in regsCurRegx.fetchall():    

        #LLena las celdas del excel
        worksheetReg.write(row, 0, fecha, format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 1, nombre.decode('latin-1'), format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 2, paterno.decode('latin-1'), format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 3, materno.decode('latin-1'), format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 4, curp, format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 5, nss, format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 6, correo, format)
        if enviocorreo == 0:
            worksheetReg.write(row, 7, "NO", format)
        else:
            worksheetReg.write(row, 7, "SI", format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 8, formaenvio.decode('latin-1'), format)
        worksheetReg.write(row, 9, causa.decode('latin-1'), format)
        row+=1

    escribirLog("Se escribe toda la información en el excel. No. de Registros[%i]" % row)
    workbook.close()

    escribirLog("***Termina la generación del Excel***")
```

Comment: Have you tried giving it just the base file name without the full path? It would then be placed in your working directory, but this would rule out a typo in your full file path.

Comment: Internally `xlsxwriter` uses a [`zipfile.ZipFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) so it might be simpler to test things out with that.. (It should be part of the standard library.)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, if I tried it as "Reports / Reportes_enviados_20180806.xls" but also gives me the following error "No such file or directory: 'Reportes / Reportes_enviados_20180806.xls" and verified the permissions of the folder, and have permissions for everything, do you think the library is badly installed?

Comment: Did you try just `Workbook("Reportes_enviados_20180806.xlsx")`? with no folder specified at all? I highly doubt the library is installed improperly.

Comment: Are you adding spaces to the file paths? There aren't spaces in the example but there are in the warnings you included.

Comment: Try to create it without the "Reportes" folder leaving it only as "Reportes_enviados_20180806.xlsx" and it works, I do not know what's going on very well, but I'll leave it that way. Thank you very much for your answers, they were very useful to me.